# How To Detect Which OS Is Running The Program?

Tags: operating-system, pascal, fpc

I'm building an application that might have some different tasks depending of the OS which is running it, so I want to know if there is any way to detect the OS and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to compile separate executables for each OS, you can just use `{$IFDEF}`:

```
{$IFDEF MACOS} // Mac OSX
{$IFDEF WIN64} // Windows 64 bit
{$IFDEF WIN32} // Windows 32 bit app 
{$IFDEF Linux} // Linux
{$IFDEF UNIX}  // UNIX
```

You can differentiate between Win32 and Win64 from a 32-bit app using `SysUtils.TOSVersion.Architecture`; the possible values are `arIntelX86` and `arIntelX64`, and generically (without regard to "bitness") between Windows and MacOS with `TOSVersion.Platform`.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks for the correction to the typo and the additional defines.

Comment: macos X is actually define "darwin".  "macos" is classic macos, which was also briefly supported. BSD also is defined for all BSDs (now OpenBSD, FreeBSD and Darwin/OSX)